# Auto layout is ignoring the trailing space constraint only on one particular view, or so it seems

Tags: ios, autolayout

I'm trying to get some subviews inside of a view inside of a scroll view to extend the width of the view minus 16px margin on either side. I have no width constraint set, only height constraint, vertical spacing constraint, and leading/trailing spacing constraint. This exactly same procedure worked on a different view but in this new view auto layout is not maintaining 16px spacing for the trailing space constraint. Below is a screenshot of what is happening:

[image]

As you can see, even though there's a 16px trailing constraint, when I update frames and/or run the app, the register button just snaps all the way back to a 194.5px trailing space. I don't believe I have a relative margin set but I'm not certain.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the priority on the trailing constraint? What is the priority of the hugging?

Comment: Which constraint is hugging? And for the trailing constraint the priority is 1000.

Comment: Content hugging priority, just off the bottom of your screen shot. Do you get any auto-layout errors logged at runtime? Is this on iOS7 and / or 8? What size classes are the other constraints enabled and disabled for?

Answer (score 0):

Your image states that you have some sort of misplaced view.
The orange line states that this isn't what will actually be rendered, but the (+194.5) one. 
Please try to do the following steps and see if it helps.

Before:
[image: Before]

The misplaced view:

[image]
[image]

After I update frame:

[image]

Did you try to do these steps?
If it doesn't help, post an image after you click 'update fames'
Thanks